# Create a MySQL function

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-function

In my mysql dababase i have 2 tables "**brands**" and "**models**"

```
CREATE table brands (
id int(11),
brand_name varchar(20));

CREATE TABLE models (
id int(11),
idBrand int(11),
model_name varchar(20));
```

I want to write a functions allowing me to display a result of requet like this :

```
Brand_name      model_name
brand_1         model_1_1, model_1_2, model_l_3
brand_2         model_2_1, model_2_2, model_2_3
```

Comment: Why you need in ***function***?

Comment: What's your exact question? Have you tried anything so far which is not working yet? Then please share sample input data, the matching expected data, and your attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` function:

```
select b.id, max(brand_name), group_concat(model_name)
from brands b join models m
on b.id = m.idBrand
group by b.id;
```

Or if you want not to select id, this is also valid:

```
select brand_name, group_concat(model_name)
from brands b join models m
on b.id = m.idBrand
group by brand_name;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=15e865c99a9a252043daf71281379e78)

If you want to have a whole set returnd then you can create procedure:

```
CREATE procedure test_proc ()

BEGIN

 select brand_name, group_concat(model_name) model_name
 from brands b join models m
 on b.id = m.idBrand
 group by brand_name;

END
```

And call it like this:

```
call test_proc();
```

Because as you can see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-function-udf.html functions can not return this kind of data...

Comment: Perfect answer. I like it! I've given you a vote up.

Comment: can i write this request in procedure or function

Comment: Why and please explain how did you plan to use it ?

Comment: Hi @brahimzaid, As you can see I have updated my answer. Does this now answers your question?

Comment: Hi @brahimzaid, I would appriciete your feedback? Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired results by using **group_concat** Mysql Function as below:

```
Select br.brand_name, 
group_concat(mod.model_name SEPARATOR ',') AS model_name
from brands br join models mod
on br.id = mod.idBrand
group by br.brand_name;
```

I hope this helps!